# Not getting data from JSON file while questing using Volley

Tags: kotlin, android-volley, get-request

I am using the YouTube Data API for getting details of youtube videos.
I am using this url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videosid=JbhBdOfMEPs&key=API_KEY&part=snippet"

This is my main kt file in which I am requesting from API

```
import android.app.VoiceInteractor
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.YouTubePlayer
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.listeners.AbstractYouTubePlayerListener
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.options.IFramePlayerOptions.Companion.default
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.lang.Exception

class MathPlayer2 : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var query : RequestQueue
    lateinit var details:ArrayList<data_math>
    lateinit var youtubeNewPlayer:YouTubePlayerView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_math_player2)
        youtubeNewPlayer = findViewById(R.id.youtubeNewplayer)
        initializingPlayer(youtubeNewPlayer,"JbhBdOfMEPs")
        query = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val uid_array = arrayOf("JbhBdOfMEPs" , "rV7WjNWHOsI" , "fr04p6Ar9ic" , "qyW2mWvvtZ8",
            "AkWtUOwlUgs","jC4SWFag6Qw","n9fgcm0Pwgs","-Xt4UDk7Kzw","YFyOsvnr9ig")

        details = ArrayList<data_math>()
        for(x in uid_array) {
            gettingRequest(x)
        }
        if(details.isEmpty()){
            println("///////////////////////////////////////////////")
            println("EMPTY")
        }
        val recyclerView : RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.mathRecyclerView)
        val itemAdapter = Math_Recycler_Adapter(details)
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL , false)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
        recyclerView.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
        recyclerView.adapter = itemAdapter

    }

//Herer I AM REQUESTING


    private fun gettingRequest(x:String)
    {
        val url :String = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=" + x+
                "&key=API_KEY&part=snippet"

        val jsonObject = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,null ,Response.Listener<JSONObject> {
            val success = it.getBoolean("success")
            if(success)
            try{

                val items = it.getJSONArray("items")
                val item = items.getJSONObject(0)

                val uid = item.getString("id")
                val snippet = item.getJSONObject("snippet")
                val title_video = snippet.getString("title")
                val description = snippet.getString("description")
                val thumbnails = snippet.getJSONObject("thumbnails")
                val maxres = thumbnails.getJSONObject("maxres")
                val url = maxres.getString("url")
                val width = maxres.getInt("width")
                val height = maxres.getInt("height")
                details.add(data_math(uid,title_video))
            }`enter code here`
            catch (e:JSONException){
                Toast.makeText(this,"error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

        }, { error -> error.printStackTrace() })
        query.add(jsonObject)
    }
    private fun initializingPlayer(youtubePlayer: YouTubePlayerView, str:String){
        youtubePlayer.addYouTubePlayerListener(object : AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
            override fun onReady(@NonNull youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer) {
                val videoId = str
                youTubePlayer.cueVideo(videoId, 0f)
            }
        })
        youtubePlayer.getPlayerUiController().setFullScreenButtonClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            if (youtubePlayer.isFullScreen()) {
                youtubePlayer.exitFullScreen()
                window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE
                // Show ActionBar
                if (supportActionBar != null) {
                    supportActionBar!!.show()
                }
            } else {
                youtubePlayer.enterFullScreen()
                window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                // Hide ActionBar
                if (supportActionBar != null) {
                    supportActionBar!!.hide()
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This is my XML file for main activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MathPlayer2">

    <com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/youtubeNewplayer"
        >

    </com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/mathRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/youtubeNewplayer"
        >

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my data class

```
package com.example.internproject1

import android.media.Image
import android.widget.ImageView

data class data_math(val uid:String, val title:String) {

}
//, val description:String ,val url :String , val width:Int,val height :Int
```

This is my recyclerView Adapter file

```
package com.example.internproject1

import android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import org.w3c.dom.Text

class Math_Recycler_Adapter(val details:ArrayList<data_math>):RecyclerView.Adapter<Math_Recycler_Adapter.MathViewHolder>() {

    class MathViewHolder(v: View) :RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
        var VideoTitle:TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.math_title)

    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MathViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.math_recycler_view , parent,false)
        return MathViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MathViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val detail = details[position]
        holder.VideoTitle.text = detail.title

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return details.size
    }
}
```

an this is RecyclerView XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/math_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/digital_learning"
            android:scaleType= "fitCenter"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/math_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:layout_below="@+id/math_thumbnail"
            />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_more"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/more"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/math_title"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/math_title"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/math_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Description"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/math_title"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the api data

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
    "etag": "AQ42JMutl9MwSwr5zWkZJNiFoaM",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "6F4WX_k2_NkRd0js2j7nAdAkhEA",
            "id": "JbhBdOfMEPs",
            "snippet": {
                "publishedAt": "2017-08-02T16:44:44Z",
                "channelId": "UC0cd_-e49hZpWLH3UIwoWRA",
                "title": "Introduction to Mathematics",
                "description": "Everyone hates math, right? Wrong! I like math. Mathematicians like math, presumably. Physicists like math, usually. People who hate math just don't understand it. But like that weird ethnic food you're scared of trying or that odd kid in class that doesn't say much, if you come to understand something it's not so scary. In fact, if we can learn enough about math, we will come to love it",
                "thumbnails": {
                    "default": {
                        "url": "<https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JbhBdOfMEPs/default.jpg>",
                        "width": 120,
                        "height": 90
                    },
                    "medium": {
                        "url": "<https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JbhBdOfMEPs/mqdefault.jpg>",
                        "width": 320,
                        "height": 180
                    },
                    "high": {
                        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JbhBdOfMEPs/hqdefault.jpg",
                        "width": 480,
                        "height": 360
                    },
                    "standard": {
                        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JbhBdOfMEPs/sddefault.jpg",
                        "width": 640,
                        "height": 480
                    },
                    "maxres": {
                        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JbhBdOfMEPs/maxresdefault.jpg",
                        "width": 1280,
                        "height": 720
                    }
                },
                "channelTitle": "Professor Dave Explains",
                "tags": [
                    "dave farina",
                    "professor dave",
                    "professor dave explains",
                    "math",
                    "mathematics",
                    "algebra",
                    "geometry",
                    "trigonometry",
                    "calculus",
                    "linear algebra",
                    "differential equations",
                    "arithmetic",
                    "math class",
                    "math practice",
                    "newton's laws",
                    "equation",
                    "addition",
                    "subtraction",
                    "mathematician",
                    "subjective",
                    "objective",
                    "inarguable answers",
                    "observation",
                    "how much tip to leave"
                ],
                "categoryId": "27",
                "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
                "localized": {
                    "title": "Introduction to Mathematics",
                    "description": "Everyone hates math, right? Wrong! I like math. Mathematicians like math, presumably. Physicists like math, usually. People who hate math just don't understand it. But like that weird ethnic food you're scared of trying, or that odd kid in class that doesn't say much, if you come to understand something it's not so scary. In fact, if we can learn enough about math, we will come to love it, because there is so much we can do with it. Watch this series to supplement your math classes, or just to learn enough math that you can become friends. It starts out super easy so don't be afraid! Okay"
                },
                "defaultAudioLanguage": "en"
            }
        }
    ],
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 1,
        "resultsPerPage": 1
    }
}
```

after Gradle build I am getting the **details**(*where I am storing all the fetched data one by one*) empty I think there is an issue with **gettingRequest()** function in the main kt file. Could anyone please help me by finding the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

success is not there in the api data
so remove this

```
val success = it.getBoolean("success")
if(success)
```